# Using Metafor or Meta for meta-analysis of proportions

Tags: r, statistics

Has anyone used these packages to create a forest plot of proportions- where the proportion and 95%CI displayed for each study is a simple proportion with an exact binomial 95%CI, and the package calculates a pooled, weighted proportion--- shown at the bottom?
Can one select the method of pooling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `metafor`, this can be done by computing the "exact" 95% CIs using the `binom.test()` function and then passing those bounds to `forest()`. There are various models that can be used to pool the proportions, so I am not sure which one you are looking for, but a "binomial-normal" model (essentially a random-effects logistic regression model) is often a good choice. This can be fitted with `rma.glmm()`. The results can then be added to the forest plot using the `addpoly()` function. Here is an example:

```
library(metafor)

dat <- data.frame(id = 1:5, xi = c(2, 5, 3, 10, 6), ni = c(20, 25, 15, 40, 30))
dat <- escalc(measure="PR", xi=xi, ni=ni, data=dat)
tmp <- t(sapply(split(dat, dat$id), function(x) binom.test(x$xi, x$ni)$conf.int))
dat$ci.lb <- tmp[,1]
dat$ci.ub <- tmp[,2]

res <- rma.glmm(measure="PLO", xi=xi, ni=ni, data=dat)

par(mar=c(5,4,1,2))
with(dat, forest(yi, ci.lb=ci.lb, ci.ub=ci.ub, ylim=c(-1.5,8), xlim=c(-.5,1), refline=predict(res, transf=transf.ilogit)$pred))
addpoly(res, row=-1, transf=transf.ilogit)
abline(h=0)
text(-0.5, 7, "Study", pos=4)
text( 1,   7, "Proportion [95% CI]", pos=2)
```

The results from the model (`res`) are:

```
Random-Effects Model (k = 5; tau^2 estimator: ML)

tau^2 (estimated amount of total heterogeneity): 0
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):      0
I^2 (total heterogeneity / total variability):   0.00%
H^2 (total variability / sampling variability):  1.00

Tests for Heterogeneity:
Wld(df = 4) = 1.7806, p-val = 0.7760
LRT(df = 4) = 2.0582, p-val = 0.7251

Model Results:

estimate       se     zval     pval    ci.lb    ci.ub
 -1.3863   0.2193  -6.3225   <.0001  -1.8160  -0.9565      ***

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The resulting forest plot:

[image: forest plot]

Comment: Thanks, Wolfgang! Great to know! Is it possible to select the exact binomial likelihood method as described by Hamza et al?

Comment: `rma.glmm()` uses the binomial likelihood.

Answer (score 1):

One caveat regarding Wolfgang's (delightful!) answer: things go wrong when `dat$id` isn't in alphanumerical order. Basically, in this case, the plot that's being created using `forest` has the estimates and the confidence intervals in different orders. This is because `split(dat, dat$id)` returns a list with its elements in alphanumerical order.

Allow me to illustrate, tweaking Wolfgang's example above by inserting some quasi-random names which we'll shuffle along with their corresponding values in the second example:

```r
library(metafor)

dat <- data.frame(id = c("Cox","Efron","Fisher","Rao","Viechtbauer"), 
                  xi = c(2, 5, 3, 10, 6), 
                  ni = c(20, 25, 15, 40, 30))
dat <- escalc(measure="PR", xi=xi, ni=ni, data=dat)
tmp <- t(sapply(split(dat, dat$id), function(x) binom.test(x$xi, x$ni)$conf.int))
dat$ci.lb <- tmp[,1]
dat$ci.ub <- tmp[,2]

res <- rma.glmm(measure="PLO", xi=xi, ni=ni, data=dat)

par(mar=c(5,4,1,2))
with(dat, forest(x=yi, ci.lb=ci.lb, ci.ub=ci.ub, ylim=c(-1.5,8), xlim=c(-.5,1), 
                 refline=predict(res, transf=transf.ilogit)$pred, slab=id))
addpoly(res, row=-1, transf=transf.ilogit)
abline(h=0)
text(-0.5, 7, "Study", pos=4)
text( 1,   7, "Proportion [95% CI]", pos=2)
```

This produces [the same forest plot as Wolfgang's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZpex.png), albeit with names instead of numbered studies (note that I've added `slab` to `forest` for clearance).

Now, if we change the order of the studies (`id`, `xi` and `ni`), things go wrong. In the next example, we swap "Cox" and "Rao", as well as their corresponding `xi` and `ni`:

```
library(metafor)

dat <- data.frame(id = c("Rao","Efron","Fisher","Cox","Viechtbauer"), 
                  xi = c(10, 5, 3, 2, 6), 
                  ni = c(40, 25, 15, 20, 30))
dat <- escalc(measure="PR", xi=xi, ni=ni, data=dat)
tmp <- t(sapply(split(dat, dat$id), function(x) binom.test(x$xi, x$ni)$conf.int))
dat$ci.lb <- tmp[,1]
dat$ci.ub <- tmp[,2]

res <- rma.glmm(measure="PLO", xi=xi, ni=ni, data=dat)

par(mar=c(5,4,1,2))
with(dat, forest(x=yi, ci.lb=ci.lb, ci.ub=ci.ub, ylim=c(-1.5,8), xlim=c(-.5,1), 
                 refline=predict(res, transf=transf.ilogit)$pred, slab=id))
addpoly(res, row=-1, transf=transf.ilogit)
abline(h=0)
text(-0.5, 7, "Study", pos=4)
text( 1,   7, "Proportion [95% CI]", pos=2)
```

Which gives us [this weird forest plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCEYz.png). The estimates correspond with the study names, however the CIs are off: they are in the same order as the previous example (because of `split(dat, dat$id)` sorting its elements). Since we're talking about proportions, for which the CIs are not symmetrical around the estimate, it might not always be clear that things go wrong in this case. However, in this example, it is quite obvious: for "Rao" the estimate is not where you expect it in the CI (and/or vice versa) and for "Cox" the estimate is not in the CI at all.

The solution is quite simple: shuffle the results of the `binom.test` applied to the `split` back to the order of the original data (notice the end of the third line of the code):

```
library(metafor)

dat <- data.frame(id = c("Rao","Efron","Fisher","Cox","Viechtbauer"), 
                  xi = c(10, 5, 3, 2, 6), 
                  ni = c(40, 25, 15, 20, 30))
dat <- escalc(measure="PR", xi=xi, ni=ni, data=dat)
tmp <- t(sapply(split(dat, dat$id), function(x) binom.test(x$xi, x$ni)$conf.int))[order(dat$id),]
dat$ci.lb <- tmp[,1]
dat$ci.ub <- tmp[,2]

res <- rma.glmm(measure="PLO", xi=xi, ni=ni, data=dat)

par(mar=c(5,4,1,2))
with(dat, forest(x=yi, ci.lb=ci.lb, ci.ub=ci.ub, ylim=c(-1.5,8), xlim=c(-.5,1), 
                 refline=predict(res, transf=transf.ilogit)$pred, slab=id))
addpoly(res, row=-1, transf=transf.ilogit)
abline(h=0)
text(-0.5, 7, "Study", pos=4)
text( 1,   7, "Proportion [95% CI]", pos=2)
```

which gives us [a proper forest plot again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYCDB.png), sorted according to our dataset.

Sorry for not embedding the images, I'm not allowed to do that yet since I'm a noob here :).

Comment: Good catch. Indeed, one has to be careful when using `split()`. Alternatively, one could use `split(dat, factor(dat$id, levels=dat$id))` to force the correct order of the levels.